# ORA-904: Invalida identifier but it references not the column name, but the value I give

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am trying to execute in php but it gives me the error ORA-904"invalid identifier". I have a column called "ZONA", but the error says that the invalid identifier isn't "ZONA", but instead the value of the variable

I already did some of these queries but with other variables and tables and I didn't get this error.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM INMUEBLES WHERE ZONA= ". $nuevaBusqueda['zona'];
```

Comment: Use quotes around your values and use parameterized queries.

Comment: Don't know why but it worked (despite not being necesary in other queries). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would have worked in other places because they were numbers, not strings.